# How does one do development on with facebook's oauth when there is a domain name restriction?

Tags: facebook

Facebook does not allow callbacks on ip addresses. So how does one test their facebook authentication oauth sign up flow on their own computer as opposed to the production domain?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that restriction. is it solvable using dynamic DNS? also: your provider doesn't have a PTR record for your IP? a 3rd option: if you know of a site that has a phpinfo page, POST to there and you can get the callback parameters from the querystring. of course, then they could very well be compromised.

Comment: my bad, not POST, but use a phpinfo page as your callback and you can get your parameters from it.

Comment: What do you mean? We do it in Developer settings by not putting anything in app domain, and just specifying the local IP (eg 192.168.1.10) in the Website box. oauth works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Point `yourdomain.com` to your test server (`127.0.0.1`, if I got that right) by editing your `/etc/hosts` file.

And yes, by `/etc/hosts` I also meant `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, obviously.

Comment: oh, right! duh... +1 I forgot the mechanism is that Facebook simply sends a Location: header with the parameters in the querystring